# Как создать предикат транслируемый в SQL?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, expressions

При составлении LINQ, которые в дальнейшем транслируется в SQL, появилось большое количество повторяющихся условий, которые хочется вынести в одно место. Например:

```
// in PersonService
personsQuery = personsQuery.Where(x => x.Address.Name.Contains(searchString) || x.Address.Phone.Contains(searchString));

// in AddressService
addressQuery = addressQuery.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchString) || x.Phone.Contains(searchString));

// условия идентичны, разница только в сущности коллекции
```

*В целом сущностей с такими условиями больше, но рассмотрим только Address и Person, чтобы показать пример, в котором Адрес рассматривается и как самостоятельная сущность и как часть другой*

Если создать обычный предикат, то при кастинге LINQ-to-SQL получим ошибку:

```
// predicate
public bool FindAddressPredicate(Address address, string search)
{
    return address.Name.Contains(searchString) || address.Phone.Contains(searchString);
}

// using
personsQuery = personsQuery.Where(x => FindAddressPredicate(x.Address, search));
```

> The LINQ expression '*expression*' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

Следующим шагом стала попытка написать метод расширения для коллекции. Проблемным моментом стал Expression для выбора Адреса из любого объекта.

```
// Extension method
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyAddressFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> list, Expression<Func<T, Address>> addressSelector, string search)
{
    return list.Where(x => addressSelector(x).Name.Contains(searchString) || addressSelector(x).Phone.Contains(searchString));
}

// using
personsQuery = personsQuery.ApplyAddressFilter(x => x.Address, search));
```

Такой код не компилируется по причине того, что addressSelector является Выражением, а не методом, в связи с чем возникает ошибка "Method name expected". Если же выражение скомпилировать, то получим ошибку трансляции

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyAddressFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> list, Expression<Func<T, Address>> addressSelector, string search)
{
    var selector = addressSelector.Compile();
    return list.Where(x => selector(x).Name.Contains(searchString) || selector(x).Phone.Contains(searchString));
}
```

> The LINQ expression '... Where(n => Invoke(__selector_0, n) ...' could not be translated

Можно ли создать Выражение которое позволяет указать, как выбрать необходимую для фильтрации сущность и при этом будет транслироваться в SQL?

Или это тупиковый способ и есть более подходящее решение?

**UPD 1:**
Упрощенная структура классов:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

}

public class Address
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ограничений на изменение модели БД нет

Comment: попробуйте public Expression<bool>  FindAddressPredicate

Comment: Не совсем понятна идея:
Если речь про Expression<Func<Address, bool>>, то проблемы описаны в посте - не получается достать Address в Expression tree 
Если действительно про Expression<bool>, то не понимаю как получить Expression из обычного предиката. 
Был бы признателен, если бы вы объяснили свою идею чуть подробнее

Comment: @imarryel Покажите структуру `Person` и `Address`

Comment: @User, дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня получилось так:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyAddressFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> list, string search)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Address))
        return list.Where(x =>
            (x as Address)!.Name.Contains(search) ||
            (x as Address)!.Phone.Contains(search));
    else
        return list.Where(x =>
            EF.Property<Address>(x, "Address").Name.Contains(search) ||
            EF.Property<Address>(x, "Address").Phone.Contains(search));
}
```

Использование:

```
var addressQuery = db.Addresses.ApplyAddressFilter(searchString).ToList();
var personsQuery = db.Persons.ApplyAddressFilter(searchString).ToList();
```

Если запрос вызывается на таблице `Address`, то тип используется напрямую. На всех других таблицах будет использовано свойство `Address` через метод [EF.Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-6.0).

Проверил на EF Core 6 и Sql Server. Генерируются нормальные sql-запросы.

---

Код в синтаксисе методов (method syntax) выглядит неуклюже из-за повторяющихся частей `(x as Address)` и `EF.Property<Address>(x, "Address")`. Если нужно будет проверять более двух свойств, то код станет выглядеть совсем громоздко.

Решить это можно с помощью оператора `let` в синтаксисе запросов (query syntax):

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyAddressFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> list, string search)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Address))
        return from x in list
               let address = x as Address
               where
                   address.Name.Contains(search) ||
                   address.Phone.Contains(search)
               select x;
    else
        return from x in list
               let address = EF.Property<Address>(x, "Address")
               where
                   address.Name.Contains(search) ||
                   address.Phone.Contains(search)
               select x;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, такое решение работает и подходит 
В целом такой подход рассматривал, не знал про то, что можно кастить через EF.Property